What is the new best way to mass-set values of an existing dataframe in pandas?
Imagine I have a dataframe where I wish to change the existing values based on their location in the frame (e.g. iloc):
(Pdb) df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]], columns=["let", "num"])
(Pdb) df
  let  num
0   a    1
1   b    2
2   c    3

What is the proper way with copy-on-write to do it in pandas?
(Pdb) df["num"].iloc[1:] = 22
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: ChainedAssignmentError: behaviour will change in pandas 3.0!
You are setting values through chained assignment. Currently this works in certain cases, but when using Copy-on-Write (which will become the default behaviour in pandas 3.0) this will never work to update the original DataFrame or Series, because the intermediate object on which we are setting values will behave as a copy.
A typical example is when you are setting values in a column of a DataFrame, like:

df["col"][row_indexer] = value

Use `df.loc[row_indexer, "col"] = values` instead, to perform the assignment in a single step and ensure this keeps updating the original `df`.

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

(Pdb) df
  let  num
0   a    1
1   b   22
2   c   22

I can do it today but with an ominous warning!
Thanks,
/YGA

Have you tried implementing the method suggested in the very warning? df.loc[row_indexer, "col"] = values?

Does't seem to work with iloc.

The suggested method doesn't use iloc, it uses loc.

I know.  I want to use iloc.

As per the suggested duplicate, you can do df.loc[df.index[1:], 'num'] = 22 or with iloc: df.iloc[1:, df.columns.get_loc('num')] = 22.

That's it; it's the df.columns.get_loc that I was missing.

As per ouroborus1's comment:
df.iloc[1:, df.columns.get_loc('num')] = 22

